# how to filter multiple filed with python Regular expression

Tags: python, expression

May I know how should I design the filter to get multiple match for a filed? Here is an example, I need to fitler the all uplinkVolume from below paragraph to summary the all uplink volume.

How can I do that with Python Regular expression?

> { extensionType:{1} length:{48} serviceList:{:{serviceCode:{2000} uplinkVolume:{268266} downlinkVolume:{11761667} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{99} uplinkVolume:{296} downlinkVolume:{923} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } } changeTimeList:{-} recordOpeningTime:{-} duration:{-} transparentVSA:{-} cdrType:{-} createTime:{-} chargingType:{-} roaming:{-} profile:{-} nsapi:{-} lastActivityTimeUpLink:{-} lastActivityTimeDownLink:{-} zoneId:{-} daylightSavingTime:{-} localTimeZone:{-} sgsnChange:{-} sessionID:{-} recordOpeningTimeZone:{-} saRecordChangeTime:{-} saRecordChangeTimeZone:{-} acctSessionId:{-} acctTerminateCause:{-} }
>   { extensionType:{1} length:{144} serviceList:{:{serviceCode:{281} uplinkVolume:{4021} downlinkVolume:{4125} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{2000} uplinkVolume:{266097} downlinkVolume:{9213530} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{99} uplinkVolume:{1129} downlinkVolume:{2733} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{281} uplinkVolume:{104} downlinkVolume:{135} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{2000} uplinkVolume:{260058} downlinkVolume:{11145532} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{99} uplinkVolume:{294} downlinkVolume:{811} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } } changeTimeList:{-} recordOpeningTime:{-} duration:{-} transparentVSA:{-} cdrType:{-} createTime:{-} chargingType:{-} roaming:{-} profile:{-} nsapi:{-} lastActivityTimeUpLink:{-} lastActivityTimeDownLink:{-} zoneId:{-} daylightSavingTime:{-} localTimeZone:{-} sgsnChange:{-} sessionID:{-} recordOpeningTimeZone:{-} saRecordChangeTime:{-} saRecordChangeTimeZone:{-} acctSessionId:{-} acctTerminateCause:{-} }

Comment: Please _don't_ try to use regex to parse JSON content.  Python must have some JSON libraries which can reliably do what you want to do here.

Comment: okay, thanks to give an alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

This expression finds all uplinkVolume fields and places the values of the found fields into a group. Values equal to " - " are not included in the sample.

```
r"uplinkVolume:{(\d+)}"
```

Example of use:

```
import re

json_text = "YOUR_JSON_TEXT_FROM_THE_EXAMPLE_ABOVE"
field_values = re.findall(r"uplinkVolume:{(\d+)}", json_text)
# field_values = ['268266', '296', '4021', '266097', '1129', '104', '260058', '294']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
string = '{ extensionType:{1} length:{48} serviceList:{:{serviceCode:{2000} uplinkVolume:{268266} downlinkVolume:{11761667} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{99} uplinkVolume:{296} downlinkVolume:{923} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } } changeTimeList:{-} recordOpeningTime:{-} duration:{-} transparentVSA:{-} cdrType:{-} createTime:{-} chargingType:{-} roaming:{-} profile:{-} nsapi:{-} lastActivityTimeUpLink:{-} lastActivityTimeDownLink:{-} zoneId:{-} daylightSavingTime:{-} localTimeZone:{-} sgsnChange:{-} sessionID:{-} recordOpeningTimeZone:{-} saRecordChangeTime:{-} saRecordChangeTimeZone:{-} acctSessionId:{-} acctTerminateCause:{-} } { extensionType:{1} length:{144} serviceList:{:{serviceCode:{281} uplinkVolume:{4021} downlinkVolume:{4125} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{2000} uplinkVolume:{266097} downlinkVolume:{9213530} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{99} uplinkVolume:{1129} downlinkVolume:{2733} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{281} uplinkVolume:{104} downlinkVolume:{135} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{2000} uplinkVolume:{260058} downlinkVolume:{11145532} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } :{serviceCode:{99} uplinkVolume:{294} downlinkVolume:{811} usageduration:{-} url:{-} chargingRuleBaseName:{-} ratingGroup:{-} serviceIdentifier:{-} localSequenceNumber:{-} envelopeStartTime:{-} envelopeEndTime:{-} duration:{-} changeTimeTimeZone:{-} noOCSCreditControl:{-} uplinkPacketNum:{-} downlinkPacketNum:{-} } } changeTimeList:{-} recordOpeningTime:{-} duration:{-} transparentVSA:{-} cdrType:{-} createTime:{-} chargingType:{-} roaming:{-} profile:{-} nsapi:{-} lastActivityTimeUpLink:{-} lastActivityTimeDownLink:{-} zoneId:{-} daylightSavingTime:{-} localTimeZone:{-} sgsnChange:{-} sessionID:{-} recordOpeningTimeZone:{-} saRecordChangeTime:{-} saRecordChangeTimeZone:{-} acctSessionId:{-} acctTerminateCause:{-} }'

import re

regex = re.compile(r'uplinkVolume:{.*?}') # ? makes it not greedy and . will mach anything in curly brackets except new line
filtered_string = re.findall(regex, string)
print(filtered_string)
```

**Output :**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py x.py
['uplinkVolume:{268266}', 'uplinkVolume:{296}', 'uplinkVolume:{4021}', 'uplinkVolume:{266097}', 'uplinkVolume:{1129}', 'uplinkVolume:{104}', 'uplinkVolume:{260058}', 'uplinkVolume:{294}']
```